# How to select columns which do not have a single zero value from a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to select columns from a DataFrame, where those columns should not have even a single zero value.
How to do that?

Comment: hi bro , i saw your question about books on spaced repetition.

did you find any ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean indexing here.  Check where the DataFrame is not equal to `0`, and then use `all` to select the columns which are all `True` for that condition:

```
df = df.loc[:, (df != 0).all()]
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,5))

# zeroes in the first and third column
df.iloc[0,0] = 0
df.iloc[2,2] = 0

#           0         1         2         3         4
# 0  0.000000  0.953372  0.268231  0.500892  0.555905
# 1  0.835321  0.539232  0.697369  0.662901  0.486734
# 2  0.431325  0.662009  0.000000  0.575064  0.259657

df = df.loc[:, (df != 0).all()]

#           1         3         4
# 0  0.953372  0.500892  0.555905
# 1  0.539232  0.662901  0.486734
# 2  0.662009  0.575064  0.259657
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
df[[i for i in df.columns if 0 not in set(df[i])]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd first select all cols that have 0, sum them for a bool (False/True), invert it and use it to select subset of the data from the df.

`df.loc[:, ~df.isin([0]).any(axis=0)]`